# Can SQL Server stored procedure return complex type value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like my SP in SQL Server to return a list, is this possible?

Comment: Sql Server does not have `array's` and `list` . It is made up of `relational tables` . what complex type are you referring to ?

Comment: what do you mean by a List ? How do you define the list in SQL Server ?

Comment: [Table-Valued User-Defined Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx) are probably what you're looking for

Comment: In SP I have a statement when ran the result is a list of say users (or products), I want to get that directly from SP into my app so I can populate the grid or combo.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like list in SQL Server. It can return no of records, integer value, exception message as per the need.